# MySQL reverse-i-search

Tags: mysql

In mysql client (command line), I used to be able to press Ctrl+R to do a reverse incremental search, similarly you can do that in linux console. For some reason this does not work on my new machine.

I'm using mysql client from xampp. The reverse incremental search works on the console but not on mysql. Does anyone know how to 'enable' this?

Thanks

Answer (score 29):

MySQL 5.6 is built with the `editline` library, instead of the `readline` library used in earlier releases of MySQL. So the default key bindings might be a little bit different than you are used to.

Ctrl+R should still be bound to em-inc-search-prev by default. It works fine in my environment.

See also: [Bug #60465 MySQL-5.5 readline (editline) -- CTRL-R does not work](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60465)

> The key binding can be set via the ~/.editrc file by adding the following line: "bind "^R" em-inc-search-prev". See man editrc for more details.

And make sure your version of MySQL is not affected by [Bug #49967 built-in libedit doesn't read .editrc on linux](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49967)

If you want to see the current editline key bindings, temporarily add this line to the end of your $HOME/.editrc:

```
bind
```

Then start the `mysql` client. It will output the full set of key bindings currently recognized.

Comment: My mysql version is 5.5.16. It seems that it doesn't read .editrc. Any suggestion on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Well, I just tested a copy of 5.5.32 on my VM, and Ctrl-R works fine. So I don't have any other suggestion but try an upgraded version (at least for the client) and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.5.16 from XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7. Unfortunately I have to go xampp on Fedora 19 because I need PHP 5.3. I think alternatively I can use MySQL from the yum repo but that may open another can of worms..

Answer (score 6):

the content of added line in `~/.editrc` file is:

```
bind "^R" em-inc-search-prev
```

without double-quote in start and end.

this works for me

Answer (score 1):

To get my previous known mode to work, where page up and page down used to do the isearch using the already present input, I had to add following lines to `~/.editrc`:

```
bind "^[[5~" ed-search-prev-history
bind "^[[6~" ed-search-next-history
```

Hope this may help someone, since I could not find this solution anywhere.