# Can I use Alt+Dot shortcut to recall last argument on MySQL console?

Tags: mysql, shortcut

[We can use Ctrl+R shortcut for reverse search on MySQL console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363737/mysql-reverse-i-search). So, can we use Alt+Dot shortcut to recall the last argument on MySQL console?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Nothing happened. And I searched a mapping for that on the man page of `editrc`, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mycli](http://mycli.net/) instead of the default console tool. It doesn't support the ALT+DOT shortcut as well but it supports auto-completion and syntax highlighting which will make you much happier.