# How to search in the mysql command history

Tags: mysql

The mysql command-line client supports a history (you can use the cursor-keys to access and navigate it), but is there a way to access it (for example) in bash?

In bash you can do:

```
history | grep "command"
```

Is there something similar in mysql?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Usually this lists up all MySQL commands that have been used:

```
less ~/.mysql_history
```

Answer (score 24):

You may use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to search the history, as in bash.

Comment: @Odedra: How does this not provide an answer?

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer. Very elegant solution.

Comment: If this isn't working for you, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363737/mysql-reverse-i-search, which has [a more detailed answer along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20364428/148680).

Answer (score 5):

so, in mysql you can use:

system grep "command" ~/.mysql_history

Answer (score 2):

Open the file in vim editor

`vi ~/.mysql_history`

then you can search the pattern with `/` by entering you text.